# is there a way to create a tooltip (with no extra divs) with an inner shadow

Tags: css

We know how to create a tooltip, something like:

```
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; 
    background: red;
    margin: 80px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 15px black; //this is the problem
}
div:before{
    content: ' ';
    display:block;
    width: 0;
    border-left: red 30px solid;    
    border-right: transparent 30px solid;
    border-bottom: transparent 30px solid;
    border-top: transparent  30px solid;
    position:absolute;
    top: 60px; right: -60px;
}
```

the code above set the inner shadow of the div, but not of the sudo element, here is the [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/5092805). Is there a way to get the inner shadow to work on the border of the sudo element. Or is there another way t get the effect I need.

I know that if I needed a drop shadow I can apply a filter on the div:

```
filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 15px black);
```

But is there a way to do it for the inner shadow?

Thanks

Comment: Something like this? http://dabblet.com/gist/5093663

Comment: Thanks @Ana that's great. Can you add it as an answer so I can tick it? Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

## [*live demo*](http://dabblet.com/gist/5093663)

Change the CSS for the pseudo-element to:

```
div:before{
    content: '';
    display:block;
    width: 60px; height: 60px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: red;
    position:absolute;
    top: 60px; right: -25px;
    box-shadow: inset -10px 10px 15px -15px black;

}
```

It's not perfect, but for a subtle effect it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just use a drop shadow like this:

> -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,9))

Or you can set a background image

Hope I helped in some way :D